# apollo client useQuery progress

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, apollo-client

I am using useQuery and useEffect() reactjs hooks to query data from graphql api.

Now just show circular loading indicator but client want a top loading indicator bar like youtube web.

I saw the react-top-loading-bar but I have no idea how to calculate the percentage.

```
const {
    loading: loadingAlbum,
    error: albumError,
    data: albumData,
} = useQuery(getAlbum, {
    fetchPolicy: "no-cache",
    variables: {
      where: {
        id: id,
      },
    },
  });
```